# Stuck in Infinite While Loop, what to do

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, infinite

This does not accept any answer:

```
cout << "Restart yes or no: ";
cin >> retry;
while (retry != "yes" or retry != "no"){
    cout << "Restart yes or no: ";
    cin >> retry;
    system("cls");
}
```

If anybody can provide an alternative/fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has `retry != yes or retry != no`. This condition is a tautology, and so will always evaluate to true.

Edit your code to:

```
cout << "Restart yes or no: ";
cin >> retry;
while (retry != "no"){
    cout << "Restart yes or no: ";
    cin >> retry;
    system("cls");
}
```

If you meant to loop until a `yes` or `no` is received, then the `while` loop should run until the string inputted is not equal to either. You meant to use a logical AND in place of the OR. The code should read:

```
while (retry != "yes" && retry != "no"){
```

Comment: I like that you didn't just identify the problem, but also gave the name of the logical rule.

Answer (score 6):

**Every** string is different from either `"yes"` or `"no"`. You meant to loop as long as the string is different from **both** `"yes"` and `"no"` - this means using the logical "and" operator, not the "or" operator:

```
while (retry != "yes" && retry != "no") {
```